# Copy all txt files from all subfolders using xcopy

Tags: command-prompt, xcopy

I have been tasked with copying all .txt files from the Program Files folder as well as all of it's subdirectories to another folder I have created. The script I have:

```
xcopy c:\"program files"\*\*.txt c:\temp\myfiles\lessons
```

doesn't want to work. What am I missing?

Comment: What does this have to do with python?

Comment: I don't know anything about xcopy, but that path looks funny. What happens if you try `xcopy "c:\program files\*\*.txt" c:\temp\myfiles\lessons`?

Answer (score 14):

If you want to maintain the folder structure,

```
xcopy /s "c:\program files\*.txt" c:\temp\myfiles\lessons
```

If not,

```
for /r "c:\program files" %a in (*.txt) do @copy /y "%a" c:\temp\myfiles\lessons
```

Comment: Nice one. :) Worked for me.